# Sitecore Package Deployer

Tags: tds

I put .update files in SitecorePackageDeployer folder after installed SitecorePackageDeployer but it did not convert into json files so I want to force the deployer to start processing the .update files but when I enter the url 
"[YourSite]/sitecore/admin/StartSitecorePackageDeployer.aspx?force=1", it gives me a "The requested document was not found" error

[image]

Any Ideas??

Comment: Sounds like that file is not installed on your server. Did you verify it's present in your Website folder?

Comment: The URL in your screenshot is mistyped and I assume you are actually going to the proper URL??? “sartstiecorepackagedeployer”

Comment: If you installed the Sitecore package deployer in Sitecore 9 then Copy the StartSitecorePackageDeployer.aspx from app_data folder and paste in website root folder.
Then it will start to work as expected. Thanks
Vikas Kumar